# Providing an answer to a "protected" Topic

Tags: discussion, support, protected-questions

I rcently came across the following Topic:

[What can I do if I am asked to learn different programming languages very frequently?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/131779/what-can-i-do-if-i-am-asked-to-learn-different-programming-languages-very-freque)

I am a Human Resources Professional with some experience in this matter and would have to disagree (to some extend) with most oft the answers and would be willing to provide some professional insight into this matter. However since the topic is protected I am unable to do so. I would not like to answer some other topic just to gain the needed reputatione since I would consider this to be spam.

Is there a different way to provide a (maybe valuable) contribution to this protected topic?

Comment: This particular question is also closed, so even if it were unprotected you would still not be able to answer it.

Comment: Thank your for the information, this hsa not been visible until now. Is it possible to reopen the topic?

Comment: @DavidK that doesn't address the question

Comment: @RichardU Yes, I know, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. I still thought it was useful information for the OP to have though.

Comment: @MrTony If you would like that question reopened, the best way is to create another Meta post requesting that. Make sure to explain why you believe the question is on-topic, or how it can be easily edited to become so. Make sure to take a look at our [on-topic definitions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be sure the question is fixable too.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to The Workplace.

The requirement to answer a protected question is only 10 rep points. One upvote on another answer, or two on a question and you're in.

Unfortunately, for every person like you, who would be ideally suited to answer a question, we have literally dozens of people who wander in, who have never contributed before, and start chiming in, often with wrong or dangerous answers, or sometimes just to troll, to limit this, the 10pt rule exists.

Answer (score 8):

***Welcome to the site!***

One of the unfortunate things about protecting questions is that inevitably you run the risk that someone with just the right knowledge is going to get blocked from answering and that's a shame. But the line has to be drawn somewhere, *anyone* could come along and say that they have the requisite knowledge. SE draw the line at requiring 10 reputation on the stack hosting the question - a pretty minimal requirement to be fair. It's something of a blunt instrument to be sure but for the mods to try and decide who can answer or not on an individual basis would be wildly impractical.

As mentioned in the comments it's something of a moot point in this case as the question is currently on hold (and therefore can't be answered) anyway, but stick around - I'm sure there will be lots of questions that someone in your line of work can provide valuable insight on and next time this situation arises it won't be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would not like to answer some other topic just to gain the needed reputatione since I would consider this to be spam.

Not at all, in fact, this is exactly what you should do! Answering a different question will help you familiarize with the site, and it will be a chance to help someone who didn't get an answer at all (protected questions usually have a multitude of answers already).

Personally I try to earn at least 125 rep points on every site I visit regularly. It allows to answer protected questions and also down-vote (not that being able to down-vote is a goal in itself, but only ever voting up is not a healthy voting pattern either). If you're knowledgeable about the topic, writing a single decent answer is usually enough to get 25 points.

Comment: I would add that suggesting edits also can help gain needed reputation (5 approved suggestions would suffice to answer protected questions). Personally I even prefer it over answering because this way is more convenient for me to familiarize with new site (especially if one invests a bit of additional effort into learning how [top site editors](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) do it)